# outlook getting synchronization log in unread folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I'm using outlook with a hosted exchange account. I keep getting these "synchronization log" emails appearing in my built-in "unread mail" folder in outlook. This makes my "unread mail" folder less useful when I get a flood of these sync log emails.

How can I stop this? Preferably on the Exchange server level.

Sample email:

```
22:22:37 Synchronizer Version 14.0.6025
22:22:37 Synchronizing Mailbox 'my name'
22:22:37 Synchronizing local changes in folder 'Inbox'
22:22:38 Uploading to server 'thedomainname'
22:22:38 Synchronization of some deletions failed.
22:22:38         [80040115-514-80040115-130]
22:22:38         Network problems are preventing connection to Microsoft Exchange.
22:22:38         Microsoft Exchange Information Store
22:22:38         For more information on this failure, click the URL below:
22:22:38         http://www.microsoft.com/support/prodredirect/outlook2000_us.asp?err=80040115-514-80040115-130
22:22:38       1 view(s)/form(s) deleted in online folder
22:22:38 Done
```

Comment: Couldn't you just write a rule that deletes or marks them read?

Comment: So every single user has to make a client side rule to delete or mark as read?

Comment: This question appeared to be referring to a single user

Comment: I've had the same problem since using Outlook 2013 with hosted Exchange. It seems to be common issue that pervades everyone in the Office. Microsoft doesn't seem to care about writing mediocre software... As long as they have the majority of the market share, this attitude will not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can tell you is that Microsoft is [aware of the issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2606009). But the solution is not available at the moment :-( This bug annoys me too.